# Why does my USB keyboard keep turning off whenever I play video games?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I’ve recently come across a problem with my computer. I thought my keyboard was starting to break as I have had it for almost three years straight.

It would turn off whenever I would play video games and only when I plugged it back in did it work again, but then turn off 15 seconds afterwards. So I bought a new keyboard thinking my old one was broken. The new keyboard arrives and the same day it has the same exact issue.

I’ve searched the internet a lot and I can’t find the exact reason why. My new keyboard isn’t broken and it doesn’t need any updates. neither can i even find it on device manager.

It works completely fine on anything else other than games. I’ve had my PC for almost five years and the only thing I can think of is that my PC is starting to break down.

My mouse works perfectly fine and i have swapped usb ports with the keyboard and mouse and that also doesn’t seem to be the issue.

Comment: *All* games, or just one or more with a protection scheme, e.g., to prevent cheating?

Comment: Could be a power supply issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik i’ve just tried different games and it appears online games are being turning it off completely. but i’ve come to find that some offline games also turn it off as well. sometimes some games just make the lights turn off rather than the actual keyboard.